# Which imagick ini file is being used by php 8.0.25?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2. My /etc/php.d/ directory contains two imagick ini files. 20-imagick.ini reads extension=imagick and 40-imagick.ini reads extension=imagick.so

If I run the command "php -m | grep imagick" I receive the following - PHP Warning:  Module "imagick" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0

How do I determine which ini file is the correct one? How do I remove the other one?

I wanted to confirm imagick was installed.

Comment: Run `php -i` to list php info including read ini files. https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php

Comment: So I commented extension=imagick.so in the 40-imagick.ini file and everything seems good.